# Remove hyperlinks from citations

Tags: citing, links

My inline citations and bibliography have colored hyperlink boxes around them. I need to remove them. Here are the packages I have loaded:

```latex
\documentclass[letterpaper,man,natbib]{apa7}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,natbib]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{Literature_Review.bib}
%\usepackage[letterpaper, portrait, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Page \thepage}
\lhead{LITERATURE REVIEW}
\rfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{1.2cm}
\begin{document}
\input{titlepage}
```

Output looks like this:

[image: screen shoot]

Comment: Try `biblatex` package option `hyperref=false`.

Comment: Thank you that worked for the inline citations. Is there a way to remove the links in the bibliography for websites cited?

Comment: Maybe sth like `\AtBeginEnvironment{thebibliography}{\let\url\nolinkurl}` or `\AtBeginBibliography{\let\url\nolinkurl}` will work. Haven't tried it.

Comment: Do you want to remove the links or only the colored boxes?